# Cannot sign binaries from 3rd-party library in Xcode iOS project

Tags: python, ios, xcode

I am building an iOS app and I wish to embed Python. I am currently following a tutorial from [Beeware](https://github.com/beeware/Python-Apple-support/blob/main/USAGE.md) and it works but only on the iOS simulator on my Mac.

When I try to run it on my iOS device, there is (of course) an issue with code signing: `'file' not valid for use in process: mapped file has no cdhash, completely unsigned? Code has to be at least ad-hoc signed.`

The tutorial gives a signing script to add to target's "build phases", which apparently works only for MacOS so I modified it a little bit to point to my actual binaries. Here is the script:

```
set -e
echo "Signing as $EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY_NAME ($EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY)"
find "$CODESIGNING_FOLDER_PATH/python-stdlib/lib-dynload" -name "*.so" -exec /usr/bin/codesign — force — sign "$EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY" -o runtime — timestamp=none — preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements,flags — generate-entitlement-der {} \;
```

But when I try to build, I get this error:

```
Signing as Apple Development: me@icloud.com (XXX) (XXXXXXXXX)
find: /Users/lg/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-xxxxxxxxx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.app/python-stdlib/lib-dynload: Operation not permitted
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

My guess is that this is not the correct way, so how can I manage to sign those Python binaries?

On the tutorial you can find this quote:

> If you are on iOS, you will be able to deploy to an iOS simulator without specifying development team; however, you will need to specify a valid development team to sign the binaries for deployment onto a physical device (or for submission to the App Store).

I have a "Personal Team" and previously had no problem running an app on my iOS device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out: I could not run a script due to the project being sandboxed. I turned off sandboxing and was able to run the script.